# Setting the Top Icon in the Windows 10 Action Center from a Microsoft Edge Notification

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm having trouble setting the top icon of a notification sent from a Web site in Microsoft Edge.  For this scenario, this code is a good example:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function (permission)
{
    if (permission == "granted")
    {
        new Notification("Test", {});
    }
});
```

Please try executing this code from https://stackoverflow.com.  You might be prompted to give permission, after which you should see this in your Windows 10 Action Center:

[image: stackoverflow.com Notification]

Notice the icon to the left of "stackoverflow.com."  It's the favicon or at least an icon that looks just like it.  But on other sites I operate, I can't reliably populate that icon.

For example, I operate https://mav3riq.tv.  When I run the above code on that site, notice the icon in the Action Center is some kind of default blue icon even though the correct favicon is populated on the site's tab in Microsoft Edge:

Tab:

[image: mav3riq.tv tab]

Notification:

[image: mav3riq.tv Notification]

Can someone tell me how to populate the top icon reliably?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, This method was updated.

Below is the new syntax.

```html
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) { ... });
```

Example:

```js
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
  if (result === 'denied') {
    console.log('Permission wasn\'t granted. Allow a retry.');
    return;
  }
  if (result === 'default') {
    console.log('The permission request was dismissed.');
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the granted permission.
});
```

Reference:

[Notification.requestPermission()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission)

[Using the Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)

I suggest you to use the new syntax and again try to make a test. It may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: The syntax you mentioned is the syntax I showed in my example.  So your suggestion to update my syntax changes nothing and has nothing to do with the core of my question (setting the top icon in the Action Center).  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I again try to make a test with your code and I find that I am able to set the top icon for most of the site for Action Center from Edge.

Below is my testing result.

[image]

But for that site it shows that blue icon.

[image]

I think that Action Center is fetching this icon from site and it is possible that some site are not available with this icons. So in that case it show the default blue icon.

Comment: Thank you for testing.  Your testing matches my experience.  But I can't find any reason why mav3riq.tv's icon doesn't show up.

Comment: I check the view source of all sites that I had tested for this thread. I notice that each site using different and multiple tags for favicon. It is possible that Windows 10 action center can only show the favicon from specific tags and from that site it is not able to identify the tag that used to display favicon. But this is just my assumption, There is no any documentation available that clearly describe this information.